# regex findall() only returning []

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to run the following lines, and expected Python to return ['402-292-2345'], but all I am getting from the Shell is '[]' like the final line below. What am I doing wrong? (note: I edited the original code below to reflect the missing dash.)

LATER EDIT: Additional problem came up that I think is related to using IDLE's text editor and running the Shell from there.
After a couple of your comments, I ran the lines below directly in the Shell, and returned #2 below

Ran this from the text editor:

```
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d')
resume = '''IM A SAMPLE 1234 North 55 Street Bellevue, Nebraska 68005 402-292-­2345 iasample@aol.com PROFESSIONAL REFERENCES Name Attaboy Company'''
phoneRegex.findall(resume)
[]
```

then #2 I ran this directly in the Shell:

```
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d')

resume = '''IM A SAMPLE 1234 North 55 Street Bellevue, Nebraska 68005 402-292-2345 iasample@aol.com PROFESSIONAL REFERENCES Name Attaboy Company'''

phoneRegex.findall(resume)
```

which returned
['402-292-2345'] as expected.

So, this ran as expected directly in the Shell, but not in IDLE's text editor.

Comment: There is only 1 `-` in the `402-292­2345` substring while you expect 2 in the pattern. Try `r'\d{3}-\d{3}-?\d{4}'` but it will still return `402-292­2345`. You will need to reformat the match as a post-processing step.

Comment: As a sidenote: there are online regex testing apps like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7UtxEt/2) that are really great for debugging regular expressions.

Comment: @Wiktor thank you - Not sure why that second dash was missing, as it was there in my original text editor. I also ran another experiment by putting the lines directly in my IDLE Shell, and it ran just fine.  Makes me wonder if there is something I need to be paying additional attention to when running from the IDLE text editor.

Comment: @Xukrao thanks for the link. I'm a newb obviously, and am taking a class on this that won't get to debugging for another couple weeks of study for me. Thank you all so much for your help@

Comment: As per your edit, in your IDLE example, there seems to be a weird unicode character between the 2nd `-` and the number `2345`, which is causing your issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d')
```

This pattern is trying to match 3 numbers, followed by a dash, 3 more numbers and a dash, then finally 4 more numbers.

Regexp find will not be able to transform the input format, only search through it. To match the numbers you have pointed out, try the following regexp

```
"\d{3}-\d{7}"
```

(Curly braces can be used for repetition, making the regexp slightly easier to read)

Edit: For a more generic solution (e.g. you don't know the exact input format), you could try something like this

```
(?:\d[\- ]?){10}
```

Which will match a string of 10 digits, possibly with single spaces or dashes separating some/all/none of the digits.

The funny looking `?:` after the bracket marks the parenthesis as non-matching, which essentially means that the entire match will be displayed, rather than just the contents of the parenthesis.